# API for saving images locally is not working

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to save an image locally with the help of multer but for some reason it's not working.

All other data is saved correctly in the database, but the image is not saved locally, so naturally the image path is not saved in the db.

And no error happens, so I can't understand what's happening.

Remembering that for some reason I can't use the nodejs fs module, I always get the error:

> "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in Next.js application".

I don't know why this error happens, I saw several tutorials and they all used this module, but in my project it always gives this error.

Can anyone give me some help?

API:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/clothes/', // Pasta onde as imagens serão salvas
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1000000 }, // Limite de tamanho da imagem (1MB)
});

const apiRoute = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await upload.single('image')(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
                return;
            }
            if (!req.file) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Nenhuma imagem selecionada!' });
                return;
            }
            // O caminho relativo da imagem pode ser enviado de volta ao frontend
            const filePath = `/clothes/${req.file.filename}`;
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, filePath });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Ocorreu um erro no servidor.' });
    }
};

export default apiRoute;
```

form:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const AddCloth = () => {
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");
    const [cor, setCor] = useState("");
    const [tamanho, setTamanho] = useState("");
    const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const router = useRouter();
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [fileError, setFileError] = useState(null)
    const [path, setPath] = useState(null)

    const imageInputHandler = async (e) => {
        setImage(null);
        setFileError(null);
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);

        if (!file) {
            setFileError('Por favor, adicione uma imagem');
            return;
        }
        const acceptedImageTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']; // tipos de ficheiros permitidos
        if (!acceptedImageTypes.includes(file.type)) {
            setFileError('Apenas imagens jpeg e png são permitidas');
            return;
        }
        if (file.size > 1000000) {
            setFileError('Tamanho maximo de 1mb');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', file);

            const uploadRes = await fetch('/api/cloth/upload-image', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

            const uploadData = await uploadRes.json();
            if (uploadRes.ok) {
                setPath(uploadData.filePath); // Salvar o caminho retornado pelo servidor
                setImage(file);
            } else {
                console.error(uploadData.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ocorreu um erro:', error);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event, userId, path) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/cloth/add-cloth", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ categoria, cor, tamanho, userId, path }),
            });
            const data = await res.json();

            console.log("---- Signup API Response ---");
            console.log(data);

            if (res.ok) {
                router.push("/armario");
            } else {
                console.error(data.message);
                setApiResponse(data.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Ocorreu um erro:", error);
        }
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuthentication = async () => {
            try {
                const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
                if (!token) {
                    // Redirect to the login page if token is not found
                    router.push("/auth/login");
                } else {
                    const response = await fetch("/api/auth/check-auth", {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                        },
                    });
                    const data = await response.json();
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        // Redirect to the login page if the token is invalid
                        router.push("/auth/login");
                    } else {
                        // Set the user data
                        setUser(data.user);
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Ocorreu um erro:", error);
            }
        };
        checkAuthentication();
    }, []);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event, user ? user.id : null)}>
            <div>
                {fileError && <div className="invalid-feedback">{fileError}</div>}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="categoria"
                    placeholder="Introduza a categoria"
                    value={categoria}
                    onChange={(e) => setCategoria(e.target.value)}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="cor"
                    placeholder="Introduza a cor"
                    value={cor}
                    onChange={(e) => setCor(e.target.value)}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="tamanho"
                    placeholder="Introduza o tamanho"
                    value={tamanho}
                    onChange={(e) => setTamanho(e.target.value)}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    name="image"
                    id="image"
                    onChange={imageInputHandler}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Adicionar peça de roupa</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default AddCloth;
```